# Parsing json "meta" from Dribble api

Tags: jquery, json

I have this json from the Dribble api :

```
/**/foo({
  "meta": {
    "X-RateLimit-Limit": 60,
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining": 59,
    "X-RateLimit-Reset": 1429948020,
    "Link": [
      [
        "https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/234460/shots?access_token=accesstoken\u0026callback=foo\u0026page=4\u0026per_page=2",
        {
          "rel": "next"
        }
      ],
      [
        "https://api.dribbble.com/v1/users/234460/shots?access_token=accesstoken\u0026callback=foo\u0026page=2\u0026per_page=2",
        {
          "rel": "prev"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "status": 200
  },
  "data": [
    {
```

I can get most of what I need from the "data" in my "playerShots" object, you can see just starting at the end there, like :

```
    $.each(playerShots.data, function (i, shot) {
        html.push('<div class="%id%imageFrame">');
        html.push('<img src="' + shot.images.teaser + '" alt="' + shot.title + '" data-url="' + shot.html_url + '" />');
```

But need that "Link" from the "meta" object, and if I do :

```
JSON.stringify(playerShots.meta)
```

It shows me this with no sign of the "Link".

```
{"X-RateLimit-Limit":60,"X-RateLimit-Remaining":58,"X-RateLimit-Reset":1429948980,"status":200}
```

So I can't do this :

```
JSON.stringify(playerShots.meta.Link)
```

Please help.. how do I get those links..? Preferably by reference to "next" and "previous" so I know which I have.

Comment: it is in an array so you would have to do something like ```meta.Link[0][0]``` - that should get you the first one, ```meta.Link[0][1]``` should get the next

Comment: use `link = result.meta.Link;
 nextLink =  link[0][0];
prevLink = link[0][1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
var link = result.meta.Link;
var nextLink = link[0][0];
var prevLink = link[0][1];
```

`result.meta.Link` return the array result

Comment: Totally correct for the question I asked. It Made me realise that I could not be getting the "Link" in my result. So debugged and found my variable that called page number in the url string was empty. Thus no "Link" was being returned in the "meta" of the result Thank's to you all.